# Metric system behavior in TensorFlow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to understand how the metrics system works in TensorFlow and Keras.

I have a sequential model containing dense layers, and the only metric is `"accuracy"` (as a string):

```py
model.compile(
    # [...]
    metrics=["accuracy"],
    loss="binary_crossentropy")
```

The average values associated with that accuracy were between 90% and 100%.

However, I tried to change my metrics after seing all the available classes on the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics) and I replaced `"accuracy"` with its Python-class equivalent, [`tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy):

```py
model.compile(
    # [...]
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()],
    loss="binary_crossentropy")
```

No modification was made to the dataset nor the model (apart from the metrics), and yet the values changed: The accuracy is now between 40% and 60%.

I then tried to pass an instance of [`tf.metrics.Accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/accuracy), but the results were the same as before with [`tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy).

My question is:

**Aren't `"accuracy"` and [`tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy) supposed to represent the same metric?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy()** instead of **tf.metrics.Accuracy()**, then you will find the same results.

The 'accuracy' here depends on the loss function.